# Android Intent.ACTION_VIEW Basic Authentication

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

How do I pass along HTTP Basic Authentication information to `Intent.ACTION_VIEW`? Here's where I'm firing the intent:

```
public class OutageListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

        // Get a URI for the selected item, then start an Activity that displays the URI. Any
        // Activity that filters for ACTION_VIEW and a URI can accept this. In most cases, this will
        // be a browser.
        String outageUrlString = "http://demo:demo@demo.opennms.org/opennms/outage/detail.htm?id=204042";
        Log.i(TAG, "Opening URL: " + outageUrlString);
        // Get a Uri object for the URL string
        Uri outageURI = Uri.parse(outageUrlString);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, outageURI);
        startActivity(i)
    }

}
```

I have also tried `Uri.fromParts()`, same deal. Curl works just fine.

Comment: Depends on the other end receiving the intent uri. Does your Log print what you want? is this then going to a browser?

Comment: @Blundell Log prints what I want. And outageURI.getUserInfo() displays user id and password. Android Browser just doesn't seem to send up "Authorization: Basic ZGVtbzpkZW1v\r\n" that curl does.

Comment: but you add that to the cURL command as a header? I don't see you adding it to the intent Uri

Comment: @Blundel `curl http://demo:demo@demo.opennms.org/opennms/outage/detail.htm?id=204042` works just fine. This URL encodes user id and password (as per the relevant RFCs) in the URL - in this case user id is demo (between the / and the :) and the password is also demo (between the  : and the @). Curl, and regular browsers like Firefox and Chrome, will send these up as a base64 encoded Authorization: header. Try it in any browser you want.

The problem seems to be that the Android Browser is not doing this. Confirmed with Wireshark.

Comment: then `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` is not what you want :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out you can add HTTP headers to the Intent via a Bundle, and specifically add an Authorization header with a Base64 encoded user id.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, outageURI);

    String authorization = user + ":" + password;
    String authorizationBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(authorization.getBytes(), 0);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Authorization", "Basic " + authorizationBase64);
    i.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
    Log.d(TAG, "intent:" + i.toString());

    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Hi, I used this but `Authorization` header is not reaching the server. Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42244271/showing-remote-pdf-via-intent-with-basic-auth