# How to attach Basic Auth to implicit intent

Tags: android

How can I attach HTTP Basic Auth to an implicit intent in android? I would like to be able to open files using android default apps such as gallery. I've only been able to find this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27935132/684934 and it did not work at all. I was able to get video and music files loaded with mxplayer by reformatting the uri with "username:password@" in between the protocol and the domain name but photos, video, and music with any other app will not load and debug says its a download error which makes me think it wants a specific format. Note: these all worked before I started implementing security with basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I attach HTTP Basic Auth to an implicit intent in android?

You can't.

> I would like to be able to open files using android default apps such as gallery.

There are ~2 billion Android devices, from thousands of device models. There will be hundreds of different implementations of each category of "android default apps" across those device models, as device manufacturers and custom ROM developers typically replace any AOSP defaults with their own.

Few apps that support implicit `Intent` actions support `http` or `https` as a scheme, and there is no documented means to pass HTTP authentication credentials. While it is conceivable that certain apps have their own APIs for this, you would need to integrate with those apps specifically, and the user might not have them.