# Showing remote PDF via Intent with Basic Auth

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to show a PDF located in http://myserver.com/my_file.pdf. There is a basic auth for that endpoint. I'm doing this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://myserver.com/my_file.pdf"));
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Authorization", "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

But when I debug the server side, there is no header `Authorization` in the request so I get 401 Unauthorized.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post exact url ?

Comment: `Intent`will not send a request to your server.

Comment: @NayanSrivastava it is in my company's intranet

Comment: @PrerakSola and what does it do?

Comment: @Héctor did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot share exact url, I would suggest you to open this inside a webview in your app.

```
webView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl(<URL>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an Authorization header with a Base64 encoded:

```
String authorization = user + ":" + password;
String authorizationBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(authorization.getBytes(), 0);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("Authorization", "Basic " + authorizationBase64);
```